# Fetch Combobox with Directory Name Order by Desc Order

Tags: php, date, combobox

http://dailyasas.com.pk/images/epaper/archive/page1.php

Please visit the above link to understand my problem.
I have a combobox fetching directory names in it.
The Directory names are actually dates in (dd-mm-yyyy) format.

### I just want to sort the date in Descending order (current date first, older date last)

my code is as follows.

```
<div class="search">
<form action="/images/epaper/archive/page1.php" method="get">
<?php
$dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
echo '<select id="cmbDate" name="Date" class="keyword">';
echo  '<option value="0" selected="selected"> --------- SELECT DATE ---------           </option>';
foreach($dirs as $dir)
{
echo  '<option value="'.$dir.'" ><a href="?d='.$dir.'">'.$dir.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
<input type="submit" class="asassubmit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Well you are going to have to write some code to sort the `$dirs` array before using it.

Answer (score 0):

As your directory names are unsortable by virtue of the naming convention you will have to take the result of the `glob` and convert the directory names to someting that is sortable. Sort that array and then use that sorted array to generate your output.

This should get you on the right lines.

```
$dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

$sortable = array();
foreach ( $dirs as $dir ) {
    $sortable[strtotime($dir)] = $dir;
}
krsort($sortable);

foreach ($sortable as $dir ) {
    echo  '<option value="'.$dir.'" ><a href="?d='.$dir.'">'.$dir.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Dear Bro, Thanks for your reply. I did exactly what have you suggested. But the result is not perfect. see your self by visiting the link. http://dailyasas.com.pk/images/epaper/archive/page1.php

Comment: The date format normally we use is "dd-mm-yyyy", your suggested code has just sorted "dd" but not sorting "mm".

Comment: Sorry I coded a typo. It should be `krsort()` not `arsort()` my mistake. Sorry, nobody's perfect, least of all me!

Comment: Yes i have already figure it out. :), Many thanks krsort() has solved my problem.